# Get closest cartesian axis aligned vector in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, vector

Assume you have possible cartesian axis vectors as:

> [1,0,0], [-1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,-1,0], [0,0,1], and [0,0,-1]

(yes direction matters)

Given any particular [unit vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector), what is the quickest way to find its closest axis vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming you have variables x, y, and z already as the 3 scalar components of the unit vector. Once these are given for unit vector, the largest value will be the closest to its axis.

The following code gives the tie to the first in order of definition (note the differences in the greater than and greater than/equals conditions).

Once the axis is determined, the code checks if greater or less than 0 to find if positive or negative axis is the axis vector. There is no check with equals to 0 since there is no vector that should produce this, but final else capture edge cases:

```
var v, x, y, z, xn, yn, zn;

// absolute values for direction cosines, bigger value equals closer to basis axis
xn = Math.abs(x);
yn = Math.abs(y);
zn = Math.abs(z);

if ( (xn >= yn) && (xn >= zn) ) {
    // x code
    x > 0 ? v = [ 1, 0, 0 ] : v = [ -1, 0, 0 ] ;
} else if ( (yn > xn) && (yn >= zn) ) {
    // y code
    y > 0 ? v = [ 0, 1, 0 ] : v = [ 0, -1, 0 ] ;
} else if ( (zn > xn) && (zn > yn) ) {
    // z code
    z > 0 ? v = [ 0, 0, 1 ] : v = [ 0, 0, -1 ] ;
} else {
    // oh-no we messed up code
    // has to be
    v = [ 1, 0, 0 ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Very clear and concise. For my particular application, I will actually prefer to choose a random axis if two are equal. But that can be accomplished simply with some additional `else if`s.

Comment: No worries. I love playing with these conditional logic 3d solutions, turns out I need this code for some of my own work. Why write more code than needed! ;)

Comment: Thinking about it, couldn't you leave out the `yn > xn`, and the two `zn` comparisons since they've already been checked in previous `else if`s? Then you could add a check in the else z block to see if z is zero to capture edge cases.

Comment: In your case with the random axis in case of tie, yes that is possible. Note that my code has the bias for the x-axis, both in the tie case and the zero vector. I usually check everything by force-of-habit. In your case, you could rewrite using `if` statements. The important part is the comparison of direction cosines to find longest component/closest to axis. The particulars of the logic for the `if` statements depends on use case, though I suspect that the operations would take +/- 1ms for either algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Find the maximum absolute value among the three coordinates. It will give you the closest axis. Concerning the direction, you just have to use the sign of the value you found at the previous step.

Hope it helps.